# JQuery Slide Animation + CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been searching for so long how to make a JQuery slide out on a div. There been some documentations but I've not found the one that suits my problem.

I simply want **Text 1** to slide out to the **left** and at the same time **Text 2** to slide in from the **right** and be centered on the screen.

[image]

Here's the code ^-^.

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/sru33se6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using jquery ui toggle slide. run snippet below (click anywhere to slide the text)

```js
var startWithText1 = true;
var first;
var second;
$(document).click(function() {
  if (startWithText1) {
    first = $("#text1");
    second = $("#text2");
  } else {
    first = $("#text2");
    second = $("#text1");
  }
  first.toggle("slide", {
      'direction': 'left'
    }, 500,
    function() {
      second.toggle("slide", {
        'direction': 'right'
      }, 500)
    }
  );
  startWithText1 = !startWithText1;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: teal;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.text h1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css">

<div id="content" class="content">
  <!--Text 1 slides  smooth out to the left.-->
  <div class="text">
    <h1 id="text1">Text 1</h1>
    <h1 id="text2" style="display: none;">Text 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help. Not quite what I meant tho but enough for me to understand it and use it myself!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the better way to proceed but you could try this way I did :

```css
@keyframes slide-from-center{
  from {left: 50%}
  to {left: -50%}
}

@keyframes slide-from-right{
  from {left: 150%}
  to {left: 50%}
}

body {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text h1 {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0 auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}

.text h1:first-of-type{
  left: 50%;
  animation: slide-from-center 3s linear 1 forwards;
}

.text h1:nth-of-type(2){
  left: 150%;
  animation: slide-from-right 3s linear 1 forwards;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" class="content">
      <!--Text 1 slides smooth out to the left.-->
      <div class="text"><h1>Text 1</h1><h1>
      Text 2
      </h1></div>
      <!--Text 2 should slide in to the right after Text 2 slided out. Currently commented out Text 2 below-->
      
      <!--<div class="text" style="display: hidden;"><h1>Text 2</h1></div>-->
      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```